# Automated process that runs as different user

Tags: apex, user

I have a use case where I need a record update to trigger a process that runs by a different user.  A trigger or workflow won't work as they run in the current process under the current user.  I believe time based actions can run under a different user but the minimum delay is one hour and that is too long.  I could have a batchable run and poll for a change but with only five batches running at a time, I do not want to have a batch process running often.  That's yet another delay that may be too long if the job stays in the flex queue too long.

Ideas?

It *has* to be a different user so features like without sharing do not help.

Comment: Why doe it have to be a different user? Understanding that might help provide alternatives

Comment: The issue is the user, a site guest user, doesn't have access to event but we want to insert into event.  There are compliance issue; we are required to enforce so if isCreatable returns false for the user, we can't do the insert  (even though apex would allow it).

Comment: An automated process should run in system mode.

What error do you encounter when trying to do this?  I used a custom object as proof of concept for replacing stay in touch with visual workflow, as site guest user can't update contact, and it worked fine.